# App crashes when I am trying to saved data in my model

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am developing an App using Realm. At some point in my app when I try to manipulate my model, my app crashed in an unexpected way. Here is what the stack trace said

> Can only add, remove, or create objects in a Realm in a write transaction - call beginWriteTransaction on an RLMRealm instance first

**What I am trying to do :**

lets break down my problem in parts.following is my model of app

```
@objcMembers public  class ClassGroup : Object , Codable  {

dynamic var   Id : Int? = ""
dynamic var   ClassName : String? = ""
dynamic var   TeacherId : Int = 0
dynamic var   Teachers : [TeacherMdoel]? =  []


}

@objcMembers public  class TeacherModel : Object , Codable  {

dynamic var   Id : String? = ""
dynamic var   Name : String? = ""
dynamic var   ClassId : Int = 0
dynamic var   Students : [StudentClass]? =  []

}

@objcMembers public  class StudentModel : Object , Codable  {

dynamic var   Id : String? = ""
dynamic var   Name : String? = ""
dynamic var   ClassId : Int = 0
dynamic var   TeacherId : Int = 0

}
```

now I am trying to get the list of all classes like this from realm (after saving them to realm )

```
let mClassLists = mDbHelper.realmObj.objects(ClassGroup.self)
```

Now here I get exception/error. What I am doing is, I am trying to populate my UITableView with some data that consist of all of the above models. I am fetching data and saving them in my model and trying to supply that list to UITableView but my app crash with the error I mentioned above

```
let mClassLists = mDbHelper.realmObj.objects(ClassGroup.self)

let classLists = Array (mClassLists)

for classModel in classLists {


            let resultPredicateTeachers = NSPredicate(format: "ClassId == %@", classModel.Id)

            let mTeachersList = mDbHelper.realmObj.objects(TeacherModel.self).filter(resultPredicateTeachers)

            if(mTeachersList.count > 0){

                var listTeachers : [TeacherModel] = []

                for teacherModel in mTeachersList {

                    let resultPredicateStudent = NSPredicate(format: "TeacherId == 29")
                    let mStudentList = mDbHelper.realmObj.objects(StudentModel.self).filter(resultPredicateStudent)

                    if(mStudentList.count > 0){

                        let studentsList = Array(mStudentList)

                        teacherModel.Students = studentsList[0]
                    }

                    listTeachers.append(savedDetailItem)
                }

                classModel.Teachers? = (listTeachers)



                listClassModel.append(classModel)

            }



        }
```

**In the Above code you can see that I am gathering data on behalf of Ids and saving the resultant arrays in the model. So I am getting error in the following line 
**

```
 teacherModel.Students = studentsList[0]
```

now I really do not understand why it is happening? I am not saving data in realm, I am saving in my model, still I am getting error.

Comment: Unrelated to your crash, but your model definitions are flawed. You cannot have persisted Realm properties of type `Array`, so the `teachers` property of `ClassGroup` needs to be a `List`, declared as `let Teachers = List<TeacherModel>()` and you need to do the same for `TeacherModel.students`. You should also conform to the Swift naming convention, which is lowerCamelCase for variable names.

Answer (score 2):

In Realm database, if you want to modify any model (save new data or update), the operation should be performed in a write transaction:

```
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(<your_model_objects>)
}
```

Comment: I completely understand that, but in above example I am not trying to save any thing in realm

Comment: teacherModel is already present in Realm database so if you want to modify its students you need to do this in a realm write transaction

Comment: I do want to modify , so cant I do it locally? I mean sometime I really want to modify the model, but do not want to reflect those modification into Database. Then how can I do those changes?

Comment: You should map that model in local class object to use it and modify it locally without reflecting those modifications into database. If you try to modify model which is already present in database you need to do it in a realm write transaction.